# Remove extra spaces from CSS inline element

Tags: css, list, stylesheet

I have a horizontal list, I want to be able to click on each of the list items without the following spaces.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="server-header-list">
    <li>item1: </li>
    <li>item1 value</li>
    <li>testing list item2: </li>
    <li>value of item2</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#server-header-list li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 7px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Currently the output looks like this:

```
item1: item1 value  testing list item2: value of item2
```

This is good. But when I try to click on e.g. value of item2 it selects the whole row instead of only the "value of item2" also when I click on item1, it takes one extra following space with it. Any solutions?

Comment: I don't know the `ui` element - did you mean [`<li>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because your `<li>`'s (or `<ui>`'s but i suspect that's a typo) are displayed as inline. You could do something like this:

```
li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
}
```

this should prevent the whitespace from appearing

Comment: +1 this will fix the problem as it is not just down to a typo (just make sure you add `overflow: hidden` to the parent `ul`). The extra white space appears because the browser adds space between `inline` and `inline-block` elements. You can also [try these techniques](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) if you want to keep the elements as `inline` / `inline-block`.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts thanks for the vote. Just to be curious, why the ´overflow: hidden´? should it not work fine without that, or is this a browser hack?

Comment: No problem, you were the only one focusing on the problem rather than typos. Not sure how the answer underneath managed to get 3 up-votes. Adding `overflow: hidden` is a way of self clearing floats - if you don't do that then you get a margin collapse as the browser does not acknowledge the height of floating elements: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Thanks, this works but then all the items are one after another without any spaces, when I add padding-right: 7px; then there is space between each item but lots of extra space underneath that row of items!

Comment: Is that not what you where asking for, no spaces?... Try setting up a fiddle and specifying your question...

Comment: I'll do that. I want spaces between items. But I don't want those spaces to show up when I click on the item.

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot when I add the ul { overflow: hidden} it looks good :)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend changing your `<ui>` tags to `<li>` as that is what you want I think, `<ui>` is not a valid tag. This will probably fix it

Comment: :) I know thanks, that is because of working early in the morning!!