# Part of CSS code is not working at Chrome

Tags: java, css, google-chrome, stylesheet

Hello Referring to my previous question where I wanted a horizontal list:

[Remove extra spaces from CSS inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797696/remove-extra-spaces-from-css-inline-element)

CSS:

```
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 7px;
white-space: nowrap;
```

It is working fine in IE but not in Chrome. So in chrome, list display: inline;
    list-style-type: none; are not working, I have a vertical list with dots before each item instead of simple horizontal one.

Thank,
Sara.

Comment: can you post how you implemented the list. html and belonging css classes?

Comment: You can find that in the link I have provided. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this setup, and it should work:

```
    #navBar ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    #navBar li {
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 15px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
    }
```

This assumes that the list is inside a div/span that has the id of "navBar"

Comment: Thank you worked! Another question, so I have padding-right: 7px; So I assumed that 7px should have started from the right hand side of the first item but it starts from the beginning. So I have like spaceItem1spaceItem2 but I don't want that first space! Tnx.

Comment: Hmm I think you should decrease the padding-left value in order for it to work.

Comment: paddin-left: 0px; padding-right: 7px; still have that problem!

Comment: Hmm well. I have no idea how to fix this, sorry.